# C++ (SFML) Improving network code

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, sfml

I've used SFML for now for my game's networking, I'm trying to keep the packet sizes as small as possible when server sends data to client and vice versa. I'm using TCP

This is what I had originally when I got basic networking code up and working (for packets):

```
sf::Uint8 c_id = id;
double x = Npc[id].GetX();
double y = Npc[id].GetY();
sf::Uint8 moveState = Npc[id].moveState;
bool jumped = Npc[id].jumped;
sf::Uint32 lookAtX = Npc[id].lookAtX;
sf::Uint32 lookAtY = Npc[id].lookAtY;
sf::Uint8 fires = Npc[id].firesNetwork;
bool isDead = Npc[id].isDead;
```

This is what I've updated it since so it would have slightly smaller packet size (including any combination of jumped, isDead, fires with the addition of isCrouching in one variable called data):

```
sf::Uint8 c_id = id;
float x = Npc[id].GetX();
float y = Npc[id].GetY();
sf::Uint8 moveState = Npc[id].moveState;
sf::Uint32 lookAtX = Npc[id].lookAtX;
sf::Uint32 lookAtY = Npc[id].lookAtY;
sf::Int8 spreadAngle = Npc[id].spreadAngle;
sf::Uint8 data;

if(Npc[id].isDead)
    data = DATA_DEAD;
else if(Npc[id].jumped && Npc[id].IsAiming() && Npc[id].firesNetwork)
    data = DATA_JUMPED_AIMING_FIRES;
else if(Npc[id].jumped && Npc[id].IsAiming())
    data = DATA_JUMPED_AIMING;
else if(Npc[id].jumped && Npc[id].firesNetwork)
    data = DATA_JUMPED_FIRES;
else if(Npc[id].isCrouching && Npc[id].IsAiming() && Npc[id].firesNetwork)
    data = DATA_CROUCH_AIMING_FIRES;
else if(Npc[id].isCrouching && Npc[id].IsAiming())
    data = DATA_CROUCH_AIMING;
else if(Npc[id].isCrouching && Npc[id].firesNetwork)
    data = DATA_CROUCH_FIRES;
else if(Npc[id].IsAiming() && Npc[id].firesNetwork)
    data = DATA_AIMING_FIRES;
else if(Npc[id].IsAiming())
    data = DATA_AIMING;
else if(Npc[id].firesNetwork)
    data = DATA_FIRES;
else if(Npc[id].jumped)
    data = DATA_JUMPED;
else if(Npc[id].isCrouching)
    data = DATA_CROUCH;
else
    data = DATA_NONE;
```

I am really new to networking and this code is quickly done just to test networking over the net.

I'm asking here if I could improve this any further and should I send separate smaller packets for ie. informing client of some NPC's death instead?

I can run the old code at 30 tickrate without any lag issues but anything above that I can see a small delay, haven't tested the new one yet above 30 tickrate.

Comment: First of all, instead of introducing tons of different constants like `FIRES`, `FIRES_AND_CROUCHES`, `FIRES_AND_CROUCHES_AND_SNEEZES` introduce a bit mask field, where every bit means something. This scales way better. Second, if packet size is of the essence, consider UDP instead of TCP.

Comment: thanks, that's something I havent heard yet with C++. I learned C++ basics in school and some advanced mechanics but I was really confused with the lessons they had since they included C# with C++ there. I've been reading and learning necessary C++ stuff off the net lately to build a basic game. I will sure search for the bitmask field. PS. I tried UDP originally but my game requires precision at some points so I don't want any packet loss

Comment: You could also look at SFNUL ( http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=13723.0 )

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks for introducing me bit mask field, I didn't even know such thing existed. I implemented it to my code and I am happy with the results. I guess my question was kinda pointless after all, I just didn't know about bit mask field